# Batch processing of list with different function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, data-management

`Error in UseMethod("unite") : no applicable method for 'unite' applied to an object of class "character"`

I want to batch process the data ,is there any way to make  below code work, although I know we can directly process it in the list.

````
   name = list.files("DTtreering",pattern = "^T")
   listtree = map(set_names(files,newname),read.xlsx)
   listtree%>%walk2(names(.),.,~assign(.x,.y,envir=.GlobalEnv))}
   list<-{map((names(listtree)),~unite(year_name,year,name))}```
````

Comment: The first argument of [`?unite`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html) is `data`, a `data.frame`. It is generally called with other top-level verb functions such as `mutate`, `summarize`, `nest`, and (very similarly) `separate`.

Comment: Thanks, I think the data is stored as a object, if we have the name of object, is there any way to use the name (regard as object)to analyze in unite, mutate and other's function?